# HelloGridview Android tutorial - blank screen when run

Tags: android

I was doing the HelloGridview Android tutorial, Managed to fix the errors I was experiencing and got it to compile, but when I run the project all I see is a blank screen.

Is it something to do with the folder layout in my project? I created a new folder called 'drawable', separate to the drawable-hdpi, drawable-idpi and drawable-mdpi folders

Here's the xml and the two classes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>


package com.example.hellogridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloGridView extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }   

        });

    }
}

package com.example.hellogridview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot this line

```
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

after

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Ensure that the adapter is set right .

2) Ensure that the getItem and getItemId is not returning null values . The default return values of the unimplemented methods are set to null values so we tend to ignore it : So getCount() should return the length of the array ( like you have done ) , the getItem should return the value : like this : return mThumbIds[position];

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, do you have images in your drawable folder that are the same names as those in the mThumbIds?

Answer (score 0):

just to make sure do you have your drawable folder.If not,create a new one,then copy those drawings into it.I address this issue in this way.